# Multiple model or DB for one request?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have one view which gets data from 6 models. Something like this:

```
$newstypes = NewsTypes::where('is_active', '=', 1)->orderBy('sort')->get();
$businesstypes = BusinessTypes::where('is_active', '=', 1)->orderBy('sort')->get();
$economictypes = EconomicTypes::where('is_active', '=', 1)->orderBy('sort')->get();
$politictypes = PoliticTypes::where('is_active', '=', 1)->orderBy('sort')->get();
$societytypes = SocietyTypes::where('is_active', '=', 1)->orderBy('sort')->get();

$settings = Settings::where('language', '=', $lang)->first();
```

And there is not any relation between this models. My question is should i keep it like this or there is much better way? I mean may be to get all of this just in one connection.
I am getting sometimes `Too many connections at Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic problem is, as in the other issues belonging to database connections, that the connections don't get closed.

You can enable persistent connections  in your database server

```
        'mysql' => [
            //...
            'options' => [
                \PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
            ]
        ],
```

Comment: I think this will hep more. When i posted this question, i found that it would be better to save all types in one table with additional field to determine for which model is this type. Anyway, will use `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true` to fix connection problem. Thank you very much